# How to save data in state or cache in getServerSideProps?

Tags: caching, next.js

I am building a Next.js app it is supposed to be SSR.
So I have some common data, e.g Navigation and a few other things which I do need to be server rendered and I need it on every page. But loading it on every page from my REST API in `getServerSideProps` when I move between pages doesn't seem right.

So I am looking for a way to save this information in some local cache or state and I don't load it the second time when I move to another page in the browser.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Cache-Control` header inside `getServerSideProps` to cache its response.

Example from the [Caching with Server-Side Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#caching-with-server-side-rendering-ssr) documentation:

> ```js
> // This value is considered fresh for ten seconds (s-maxage=10).
> // If a request is repeated within the next 10 seconds, the previously cached value will still be fresh. 
> // If the request is repeated before 59 seconds, the cached value will be  
> // stale but still render (stale-while-revalidate=59). 
> // In the background, a revalidation request will be made to populate the 
> // cache with a fresh value. If you refresh the page, you will see the new value. 
> export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
>     res.setHeader(
>         'Cache-Control', 
>         'public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59'
>     )
>
>     return { 
>         props: {} 
>     } 
> }
> ```

You can configure the `Cache-Control` header value as you see fit. Note that setting a `Cache-Control` value only works in production mode, as the header will be overwritten in development mode.

Comment: Yeah tried that, but didn't work in dev mode. I think next.js force use different headers to ensure no cache in dev mode. I will try this again in production mode.

Comment: @Sohail That's correct: _"**Note**: When running your application locally with `next dev`, your headers are overwritten to prevent caching locally."_. Try running the app in production mode.

Comment: Yes, the headers set correctly in production mode. Thanks.